# Is it possible to move a property to another class with ReSharper?

Tags: properties, resharper

I have a couple of properties and I want to collect them under a class to make my code more clean.

Can I do this quickly with ReSharper?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Move Static Member** is `Ctrl +R, O` in ReSharper.  They have a printable keymap which is also helpful before you learn them all (I still haven't...)  You can [find it here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper45DefaultKeymap.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Nick Craver is right about the command being there, but I don't think you can ues it on a property unless it is a static property. The option is not available for normal properties for me. What you can do is first convert it to a static property, then move it, then convert it back to being non-static?

It could at least be a first step..

Answer (score 1):

jamiebarrow is correct, you need to refactor to a static type first, see here:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_Type.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that's one of the standard refactorings built into ReSparper and IntelliJ.

Comment: For me it's a grayed out option for a property. I don't think it supports it.

Answer (score 0):

This one is quite tricky.

1. Put the cursor above the field you want to move
2. Press `Ctrl+R O`